# Logic when using two (if/then) statements

Tags: logic

Let p , q , and r be the propositions:

p: You have the flu.

q: You miss the final exam..

r: You pass the course

I'm trying to figure out how I would express this proposition in english:

(p ---> q) ---> r

My best guess does not sound correct and I think it is wrong, how do I deal with two (---->) operators?:

'if you have the flu, then you miss the final exam, hence you pass the course'

Comment: By the way, your proposition also implies that someone who does not have the flu automatically passes the course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the logical equivalence of $[x \implies y]$ and $[\neg x \vee y]$ in order to simplify things:

- $(p \implies q) \implies r$
- $\neg (p \implies q) \vee r$
- $\neg (\neg p \vee q) \vee r$
- $(p \wedge \neg q) \vee r$

So either you have the flu and you don't miss the final exam, or you pass the course, or both.

Comment: would you mind telling me which laws you used to simplify that expression?

Comment: @wannabe_n00b: One sec, I'm looking for the terminology of that in English...

Comment: @wannabe_n00b: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me out a lot. I used deMorgans law after step 3

Comment: @wannabe_n00b: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

If, whenever you have the flu, you miss the final exam, then you pass the course.

Comment: what does not make sense, i think @barak manos nailed it